# How to define, initialize and use - vector< vector < pair < int,int > , int > > v in c++?

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

Will final_result hold a series of all the results from the recursive function call? I get seg faults, but it compiles. 
I am pretty sure this won't work. But if I needed to store all results in a data structure, how would I do that?

```
vector< vector < pair < int,int> > > result;

vector< vector < pair < int,int> > > recursive_function()
{
  if(condition_met)  //never met on first call
  {
    result.push_back(a);  //a is a vector< pair < int,int> >
    return result;
  }
  else
  {
    return result;
  }
  //does something 
  recursive_function();
  recursive_function();
}

vector< vector < pair < int,int> > > final_result;
final_result = recursive_function;
```

Comment: No. The meaning of the last statement is to assign the pointer to the function to `final_result` and will emit compile error.

Comment: Please post actual c++ code that compiles.   It's impossible to tell what you're trying to do here because the code cannot work.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just make your life easier and just pass the object you're accumulating results in as a **reference parameter**:

```
void recursive_function(vector<vector<pair<int, int>>> & result) {
    result.emplace_back();
    if (rand() % 2)
        recursive_function(result);
}

int main() {
    vector<vector<pair<int, int>>> result;
    recursive_function(result);
}
```